# limit of complex line integral over a uniformly convergent sequence of curves

Tags: complex-analysis

suppose $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ is continuous,  $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$  is open and connected, $\gamma_{n}:[0,1]\to\mathbb Ω$  is a sequence of continuous curves that converges uniformly to $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb Ω$

I've been asked to prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\gamma_{n}}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$$

I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Aren't the curves given to be smooth or some other condition about being differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A stronger hypothesis that each curve of the sequence is smooth is needed. Now about an approach to get a solution. You can use the fact that $\gamma_{n}(t)=f_n(t)+ig_n(t)$ where $f_n , g_n$  are uniformly convergent sequences and converge to  $\gamma(t)=f(t)+ig(t)$for $t\in [0,1]$ . Then make the substitution for the standard contour integral into a real one and using the fact that the convergence is uniform you can pass the limit inside the integrand. Be careful though because some derivatives will emerge so you need to use the uniform convergence hypothesis again.